# Alterar propriedades de um único elemento que se repete várias vezes em minha página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma `div` com as mesmas classes repetindo várias vezes em minha página (só muda o conteúdo) e quero selecionar apenas o elemento que foi clicado.

Exemplo do código que estou utilizando:

```js
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('p').hide();
    jQuery('.readmore').click(function(){
      if(jQuery('p').hasClass('mostrando')){
        jQuery('p').removeClass('mostrando');
        jQuery('p').fadeOut('fast');
      } else {
        jQuery('p').addClass('mostrando');
        jQuery('p').fadeIn('fast');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">Titulo 1</a>
    <div class="texto">
      <p>
        Texto 1
      </p>
      <div class="readmore">Mostrar/Ocultar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Titulo 2</a>
    <div class="texto">
      <p>
        Texto 2
      </p>
      <div class="readmore">Mostrar/Ocultar</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Imagine que tenho vários `li` com os mesmos elementos `div` e `p`, que diferem apenas o conteúdo.

Quero clicar em **"readmore"** e esconder ou exibir apenas o parágrafo acima dele, mas quando clico no mesmo, o jQuery exibe ou oculta todos os `p` da página.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser que tenha maneiras mais fáceis mas desta maneira, se entendi direito, poderia fazer assim:

```
$(document).on("click", ".readmore", function(e) {
   let el = $(this);
   if(el.parent().find('p').hasClass('mostrando')) {
      el.parent().find('p').removeClass('mostrando').hide();
   } else {
      el.parent().find('p').addClass('mostrando').show();
   }
})
```

Pode ver funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ez0podh6/).

Comment: Era exatamente isto que eu estava tentando fazer e falhando, me ajudou e muito!!! Obrigado!!!